# How to use coc-pyright with python environment in container?

Tags: python, docker, vim, pyright

I want to use python environment in docker container, alongside editing source files on the host machine.
I know VSCode provides [devcontainer](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) feature, but I want to use VIM and coc-pyright.
How to do that?

Comment: Try https://github.com/fannheyward/coc-pyright/issues.

Comment: There is actually an open issue for that: https://github.com/fannheyward/coc-pyright/issues/664